# Reduce the number of switch - case with Object Literals

Tags: javascript, typescript, switch-statement, object-literal

I'm studying javascript, and I've already seen that there's a way to reduce the number of switch - case with Object Literals. I'm trying to change this method, but I am not able to reduce the number of switches

```
 static darkerColors(value: string, theme: ThemeMode) {
    const test = theme === ThemeMode.LIGHT
    switch (value) {
      case Colors.BLUE: {
        return test ? '#253F82' : '#BED1FF'
      }
      case Colors.CYAN: {
        return test ? '#066262' : '#A2EAEA'
      }
      case Colors.PURPLE: {
        return test ? '#4727B0' : '#D3C6FD'
      }
      case Colors.ORANGE: {
        return test ? '#9C2100' : '#FF9377'
      }
      case Colors.YELLOW: {
        return test ? '#6C5200' : '#F9E298'
      }
      default:
        return test ? '#32363B' : '#C9CED4'
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your not getting.... what?

Comment: The best solution would be CSS and not using JavaScript.

Comment: If I understood what you want to do, you will need to first define an object with the list of properties that you want, and then access it; Example bellow:
const ColorMap = { [Colors.BLUE] : { light: '#253F82', dark: '#BED1FF' }}
const color = ColorMap[value][ThemeMode.LIGHT ? 'light' : 'dark']
( This is just a quick example code  )

Answer (score 0):

you can use an object to handle the configuration

like this

```js
const config = {
  light: {
    blue:  '#253F82',
    default: '#32363B'
  },
  default: {
    blue: '#BED1FF',
    default: '#C9CED4'
  }
}

function darkerColors(value, theme) {
    const fallback = 'default'
    const colors = config[theme] || config[fallback]
    
    return colors[value] || colors[fallback]
  }
  
console.log(darkerColors('blue', 'light'))
console.log(darkerColors('red', 'light'))

console.log(darkerColors('blue', 'dark'))
console.log(darkerColors('red', 'dark'))
```